# Why do I have weed etc growing when I had turf?

Tags: grass, weed-control

Two years back. I dug my backyard and put turf, it was all green and lush but slowly it went brown and one month ago I mowed the garden and it was all brown, now that it’s recovering. I see a lot of what I know is weed?

My question is why there is so much of these growing and how can I get rid of it? Is it good to mow it? (I remember last year I used weed spray killer). My goal is to make my garden green and lush.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First it would be good to look into *why* your turf "slowly died." Was it unsuitable for your location, or is your garden too shady for grass to thrive, or did you not take care of it?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I would say I never took care of it. Another thing I would ask why there r species of plants growing as per picture. Is it germination or pollination?

Comment: New seeds blow in and germinate. Other seeds were already there beneath your turf and germinated when conditions were favorable (not shaded by healthy grass.) All those seeds were pollinated flowers at some point in their lives, (at least I don't see any obvious spore-based weeds here) but that has nothing much to do with them growing in your lawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices

- Either pull them with a hoe/form and hand (some of the Japenese tools are really good).
- Or spray with some herbicide (such as Glyphosate aka Roundup)

But a few weeks after spraying, you need to start spreading grass seed and watering regularly.  And then pull out the weeds as early as possible.

Note that seeds of some plants can remain dormant in the soil for several years.  So, it is vital to not let any weeds go to seed.  And if the seeds are already in the ground, then you just have to keep weeding until they are exhausted.

There are two more methods to kill the weeds.

- I used to have a gas torch weeder, that was organic, effective, very heavy and slow (so I abandoned it).
- Councils sometimes used steam to kill the weeds.  I don't know if any residential models exist.

Comment: So if I get it right, use hoe(to dug out the weed, sort of making garden grass free from those areas) then use grass seed , water them daily and if I see any weed popping up; take them our? For the last part is there any permanent solution so I don’t get exhausted pulling the weed every now and then?

Comment: Artificial grass. Or a healthy lawn, or not worrying too much about inoffensive "weeds" such as the white clover in your first picture.